# Manage_pages permission for webhooks

Tags: facebook, webhooks

We are trying to configure webhooks for one of Facebook page we are managing. 
To use webhooks product in our app, we need manage_pages permission.
So, we have created the screencast & submitted for review.
It is being repeatedly rejected saying, 'Please show the Facebook pages managed by your website on your website'
Ours is a server-to-server app. We don't have a website through which we manage this page. We manage that page by logging in to Facebook directly via https://www.facebook.com
How can we get this kind of app (which uses manage_pages permission for webhooks only) reviewed? What are we missing? Can somebody help?

Comment: Instructions specifically for submitting server-to-server apps can be found here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/server-to-server-apps